# Can I combine KineticJS and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Hello stackoverflowers,

I have a jquery bootstrap dropdown on my page with various sizes (Mens small,medium etc) and kineticJs container with text element on it. I am trying to get $('#chosenSize').text(); to show up in kineticJs container but it doesn't work. Can someone please explain me why?

This is small part of my html:

```
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-tip">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropOption" href="#msm">Mens small</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropOption" href="#mmed">Mens medium</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropOption" href="#mlarge">Mens large</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropOption" href="#mxl">Mens XL</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropOption" href="#wsm">Womens small</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropOption" href="#wmed">Womens medium</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropOption" href="#wlarge">Womens large</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropOption" href="#wxl">Womens XL</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="trigger" data-dropdown="#dropdown-1">Choose your size</a>
    <p id="sizeContainer">Your chosen size is: <span id="chosenSize"></span></p>

    <div id="container"></div> <!-- KineticJs canvas -->
```

And since there's no need to show you all code, I'll show you only the text element where I want to combine kineticJs and jQuery:

```
      var sizeText = new Kinetic.Text({
      x:40,
      y:20,
      text:'Size: ' + $('#chosenSize').text(),
      fontSize:16,
      fontFamily:'Arial',
      fill:'black'
    });
```

I tried to use plain javascript like so

```
document.getElementById('chosenSize').innerHTML;
```

but it also didn't work.
Where am I wrong?

Thank you!

EDIT:

The problem was that I didn't refresh the text and canvas elements on change.
So the answer to this question is:

```
     $('.dropOption').on('click', function() {
      sizeText.setText('Size: ' + $(this).text());
      layer.draw();
    })
```

You must put it at the end of the drawImage function (it is the main KineticJs function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the light of missing code on what happens when you make a selection from drop-down, a very likely assumption is that you are not updating the Kinetic.Text object after the selection of size. You'll need to refresh both the text set on Kinetic.Text object as well as refresh the canvas.

So in short, attach an `onSelect` event on the dropdown. Use this to call `sizeText.setText('Size: ' + $('#chosenSize').text())` and finally, `canvasLayer.draw()`

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I didn't refresh the text and the canvas. Notice: You must add that event at the end of the _drawImage()_ function.